Import from local python module when running Robot framework tests
I have the following project structure:
project
├───resources
│   │
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   │
│   ├── folder1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── helper2.py
│   │
│   └── folder2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── helper2.py
│
└───tests
    └── test1.robot

constants.py contains variables, that are used by different helper methods in folders. I import them as

from constants import *

Tests are in Robot Framework.
When I run them locally, I use VScode and RobotCode extension. And here I don't have any issues, constants are imported and used correctly.
But when I try to run tests from the command line:

python -m robot tests

I receive error with this import:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'

If i try import:

from .constants import C1

I receive:

attempted relative import with no known parent package

How should I import the constants properly?

Ok, let this be a monument to my stupidity :( I found the answer 8 minutes after I posted it.
But just in case someone else needs this:

from resources.constants import *

